# How to use RandomVariate on a random process?

Tags: syntax

I am trying to generate random numbers based on a white process `WhiteNoiseProcess[]`. 
Here is my code:

```
In[32]:= RandomVariate[WhiteNoiseProcess[], 1]

Out[32]= RandomVariate[WhiteNoiseProcess[NormalDistribution[0, 1]], 1]
```

I keep getting this result.

What I am trying to replicate is using `RandomVariate[]` like this example, but with the `WhiteNoiseProcess[]` function:

```
In[33]:= RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1]

Out[33]= {-0.532306}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `RandomFunction`, not `RandomVariate`. From a process, one gets a sequence of numbers, not single numbers.

Comment: How can make the process start at 0?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation of `RandomFunction`? Basically all the examples start at 0.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for `WhiteNoiseProcess[]` gives an example of how to generate random numbers right there, in the Basic Examples section:

```
\[ScriptCapitalP] = WhiteNoiseProcess[];
data = RandomFunction[\[ScriptCapitalP], {0, 40}];
ListPlot[data, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: OK, but the problem with using `RandomFunction[]` is that I want to generate just one number and it return 2 values, when I use this `RandomFunction[WhiteNoiseProcess[], {0,1}]`.

Comment: @LasDes Generating one number makes no sense for a process. You didn't address my comment. It sounds like there is a conceptual misunderstanding about what a random process is. If you want a distribution at time `t`, use `process[t]`